# Add timeout to CircleCI build for Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, testing, circleci

I can't quite seem to get my circle.yml file in order to extend the timeout for my iOS tests. I've basically followed their example and things run, but because my tests are slow, it never completes and times out at the 600s mark (default). I need to add the timeout modifer (somewhere) to get this to run to completion. Can someone point me to where the timeout modifier should go to allow this to run longer than 5 minutes.

**circle.yml**

```
machine:
  timezone:
    America/Chicago
  xcode:
    version: 8.3

dependencies:
  pre:
    - xcrun instruments -w "iPad Air 2" || true

test:
  override:
    - set -o pipefail &&
      xcodebuild
        CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO
        CODE_SIGNING_IDENTITY=
        PROVISIONING_PROFILE=
        GCC_INSTRUMENT_PROGRAM_FLOW_ARCS=YES
        GCC_GENERATE_TEST_COVERAGE_FILES=YES
        -sdk iphonesimulator
        -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPad Air 2'
        -workspace Augusta.xcworkspace
        -scheme "Augusta"
        clean build test |
      tee $CIRCLE_ARTIFACTS/xcode_raw.log |
      xcpretty --color --report junit --output $CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS/xcode/results.xml
    - bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)
```

Answer (score 0):

I eventually got some feedback from CircleCI on this. They weren't able to answer it completely, but gave me enough to figure it out on my own.

The issue boiled down to having all of the items on their own separate lines. YML doesn't take too kindly to that. It works when you only have 1 line and no modifiers, but breaks down pretty bad when you start adding to it. Putting the command on 1 line and just letting it soft wrap was the key. Here is what I am using and it works just fine.

```
general:
  branches:
    ignore:
      - /^wip.*/ #ignore wip branches

machine:
  timezone:
    America/Chicago
  xcode:
    version: 8.3

dependencies:
  pre:
    - xcrun instruments -w "iPhone 7" || true

test:
  override:
    - set -o pipefail && xcodebuild CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO CODE_SIGNING_IDENTITY= PROVISIONING_PROFILE= GCC_INSTRUMENT_PROGRAM_FLOW_ARCS=YES GCC_GENERATE_TEST_COVERAGE_FILES=YES -sdk iphonesimulator -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 7' -workspace "Augusta.xcworkspace" -scheme "Augusta" clean build test | tee $CIRCLE_ARTIFACTS/xcode_raw.log | xcpretty --color --report junit --output $CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS/xcode/results.xml:
       timeout: 3600
    - bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)
```